# What isTwitter callback URL?

Tags: ios

What is Twitter's "callback URL"?
When I creating an application with Twitter, I need to fill in this item.
What is it doing?

Answer (score 1):

**as per twitter document callback URL is the url which is define where user will be redirect after sign in or authentication**

> 3rd-party authentication (sometimes known as sign in with Twitter)
> allows developers to access Twitter content in order to make it easy
> for their users to sign in with just a few clicks. Developers use
> callback URLs as part of this integration in order to provide
> directions on where a user should go after signing in with their
> Twitter credentials.
>
> As part of our continued effort to ensure safety and security on the
> Twitter developer platform, any developer using Sign in with Twitter
> must explicitly declare their callback URLs in the Twitter Apps
> settings which can be accessed in the dashboard when logged into your
> Twitter account on developer.twitter.com. This means that if the
> callback_url  parameter used with the oauth/request_token endpoint
> isn't added to the allow list, you will receive an error.